# How can I filter repeated elements in array without deleting them with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am wondering and struggling on how to filter repeated objects of an array but without deleting the repeated items but instead storing them in an array inside on of the returned elements, I'm not sure if what I am saying is understandable so an example will make of good use:
My data:

```
[{letter: 'a', number: 1}, {letter: 'a', number: 2}, {letter: 'a', number: 3}, {letter: 'b', number: 1}, {letter: 'b', number: 2}, {letter: 'a', number: 4}, {letter: 'b', number: 1}, {letter: 'a', number: 3}]
```

what I expect to receive:

```
[{
      letter: 'a',
      numbers: [{number: 1}, {number: 2}, {number: 3}, {number: 4}],
    }, {
      letter: 'b',
      numbers: [{number: 1}, {number: 2}],
    }]
```

I know we look for answers but an explanation would be great.

Comment: A more sensible expected output format would make this a lot easier to achieve. Why not just: `{a: [1, 2, 3, 4], b: [1, 2]}`? This also hardly requires lodash.

Comment: I simplified my problem, my objects are much bigger but with an example for these is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `letter`, and then map the groups to object. Create the numbers by mapping the values, and omitting the `letter`:

```js
const { map, groupBy, omit } = _

const arr = [{letter: 'a', number: 1}, {letter: 'a', number: 2}, {letter: 'a', number: 3}, {letter: 'b', number: 1}, {letter: 'b', number: 2}, {letter: 'a', number: 4}, {letter: 'b', number: 1}, {letter: 'a', number: 3}]

const result = map(
  groupBy(arr, 'letter'),
  (numbers, letter) => ({
    letter,
    numbers: map(numbers, o => omit(o, 'letter')),
  })
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js" integrity="sha512-2iwCHjuj+PmdCyvb88rMOch0UcKQxVHi/gsAml1fN3eg82IDaO/cdzzeXX4iF2VzIIes7pODE1/G0ts3QBwslA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `array.reduce` method

```
arr.reduce((acc, {letter,number}) => { 
                                       let obj = acc.find(a => a.letter === letter);                                                                               
                                         obj 
                                         ? obj.numbers.push({number}) 
                                         : acc.push({ letter,numbers:[{number}]}); 

                                         return acc; 
                                       }
           , [])
```